# I can't seem to find a way to add CSS to Drupal module

Tags: php, html, css, drupal, drupal-7

I've stuck in my project with this problem:
I have a Drupal module that will ECHO long HTML code. (I am just starting with Drupal modules).
And I can't seem to find a way to add CSS to this page.

Here's my module:

```
    <?php
function kartta_help($path, $args) {
  if ($path == 'admin/help#kartta') {
    return t("<h1>kartta modulin dokumentaatio</h1>
    </br>tänne tulee karttamodulin dokumentaatio");
  }
}
function kartta_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['kartta_module/kartta'] = array(
        'title' => 'Karttamodule',
        'page callback' => 'say_kartta',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
     );
    return $items;
}
function say_kartta() {
echo '
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=620">
<title>maps form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="form.css">
<script src="scripts/form.js"></script>
</head> 
<div id=header>
<h1>Form</h1>
<h2>Upload a new map or choose an existing one.</h2>
</div>
<div id=selection>
<button id=btnNew>New</button>
<button id=btnEdit>Edit</button>
</div>
<div id=new>
<br />
<form name=newMapForm action="scripts/fallback/uploadDeleteImage.php" method=POST enctype="multipart/form-data">
Choose a file to upload: <input name="map" id="inputImage" type="file" required/><br />
Give the map a name: <input type="text" name="name" id="inputName" required/> <br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" id="btnUpload" name="upload"/>
</form>
<br />
</div>
<div id=edit>
<br />
Choose a file to edit: 
<select id=mapSelect>
</select>
<br />
<div id=afterSelect>
<p id="selectedMapName"></p>
<img alt="map" id="selectedMapImage"/>
<form name="editMapForm" action="edit.php" method="POST">
<input id="hiddenNameEdit" type="hidden" name="name" value=""/>
<input id="hiddenPathEdit" type="hidden" name="path" value=""/>
<input type="submit" value="Edit" id="btnEdit" name="edit"/>
</form>
<form name="deleteMapForm" action="scripts/fallback/uploadDeleteImage.php" method="POST" id="frmDeleteMap">
<input id="hiddenNameDelete" type="hidden" name="name" value=""/>
<input id="hiddenPathDelete" type="hidden" name="path" value=""/>
<input type="submit" value="Delete" id="btnDelete" name="delete"/>
</form>
</div>
<br />
</div>
';
}
```

It is not pretty to watch or read, but you get the point by reading only the start of it.
The .info file:

```
name = kartta module
description = test module of map php ward has made
core = 7.x
stylesheets[all][] = form.css
scripts [] = scripts/form.js
```

Comment: That's not how to create a page in Drupal. Read the [theming guide](https://drupal.org/documentation/theme) before continuing, or you're going to back yourself into a corner you can't get out of.

Comment: im aware of that, but i am making a module, later adding block to it, so i can print it into a block inside a page.
atleast in that case i think im doing it right

Comment: Nope, you should never be dumping out a full HTML page as a string like that. Use template files or theme functions. If you want to use Drupal-specific things like adding CSS through the .info file, then you have to build your page as Drupal expects. Just think it through - you put something in an .info file, and then chuck an HTML string out to the page. What do you expect Drupal's going to do with that? Perform the necessary string replacements/DOM manipulation on your arbitrary string? How would it know what format it's in? How is Drupal going to know to intercept your `print` and stop...

Comment: ...it from being displayed until the rest of the output buffering is complete? You can't 'shoehorn' random HTML into Drupal and still use it as Drupal. It has a proper structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1/You don't have to "echo" anything. Use "return" instead.
2/You don't need all the "<head>...</head>" part ; there is already a template (html.tpl.php) that handles that part for you (theming : https://drupal.org/theme-guide/6-7)
3/You should use the form API (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) instead of using raw form

To answer the original question, here is a link that explains how to add CSS : http://adaptivethemes.com/how-to-add-css-files-in-drupal-7

Answer (score 0):

You can use drupal_add_css function  inside say_kartta() function
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7